# Javascript and xml parsing

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have a XML object and I am wanting to return the text value on the node which may have a number of child nodes.

```
  <binding name="s"><bnode>b1fff4d00000000fe</bnode></binding>
  <binding name="p"><uri>http://cidoc-crm.org/P1F.is_identified_by</uri></binding>
  <binding name="zebra"><literal>copper</literal></binding>
```

In the above case i am wanting to return the text in each node were I can specify the name value of the binding.

pseudo code: 
get text where binding name value == "s" ;

I have tried this

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

so it shouldn't matter what the child node name is in this case bnode.

I hope thats clear

Thanks.

Comment: SUDO! you mean Pseudo, right.

Comment: currently I am trying to do it like so.   x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Comment: Super User DO code?  I approve of this interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to get the text content would be

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].textContent;
```

However, `textContent` is unsupported in IE < 9, so you will need to navigate through to the text node in those browsers:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].firstChild.firstChild.data;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p2SrZ/

Comment: or this... totally thought of it first... really. +1

Comment: Thanks, that one problem down just need to work out how to return the bindings name value.

Comment: @Sagarmichael: What do you mean? The value of the `name` attribute in the `<binding>` element?

Comment: @Tim Down like this. <binding name="s"> to return s.

Comment: `x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].getAttribute("name")`. I'd suggest reading some DOM specs / documentation. http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: thanks for the advice and link I was looking for some documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the `nodeValue` of an element which will always result in `null`.<sup>[[1]](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue)</sup>  What you want is the `nodeValue` of the contained text node.  Therefore, you have to unfortunately add another tier to this statement and your statement becomes

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("binding")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

This will pull the text node value of the inner elements.

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>[1] Fake citation just click the link dang it.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>